# Pull mySQL data via PHP into an array of Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

i am trying in pull my data from mySQL and convert it to a format I can then pass to google.maps API.  I am thinking mySQL -> php -> javascript -> google.maps makes the most sense but am deffinitly open to other suggestions.

So far I have connected to and successfully queried my data into an array

```
<?php
//library of mysql functions including linkDB()
  include('../sqlFunctions/sqlFunctions.php');

//Establish connection to database
  if($link = linkDB()){
    echo "connected to DB";
  }

//set up a MySQL query.  I am simply pulling geocoordinate ints, strings and boolean.
  $sql = "SELECT title
            ,lat
            ,lng
            ,titleYou
            ,descriptionAre
            ,privacyRockstar
      FROM shelters;";

  if($results = $link->query($sql)){
    echo "<p>Query succsessful.</p>";
  }else{
    echo "Query Failed";
  }

//initialize an array to store data
  $rows = array();

    while ($data = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
      $rows[] = $data;

      echo "<br><br>Loop rotation: ";
      var_dump($data);
    }

    echo "<br><p>The End of The Loop<p><br>";
    var_dump($rows);
?>
```

Now I just need to convert this data into something usable I can pass to google.maps.

Before I was pulling JSON from a text file, which worked, but I want to flexibility and stability of a database.  It was easy to parse into and array of Javascript Objects.  Then I could just call the index and the property that I needed as you can see from this function I was using.

```
function setMarkers(){
    for(i=0; i < jsonParsed.arrayOfObjs.length; i++){

//setting parameters to hand to google
      var markerOptions = {
        position : jsonParsed.arrayOfObjs[i].position,
        map : mapCanvas,
        description : jsonParsed.arrayOfObjs[i].title,
        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
      };

    //create marker
    this ['marker' + i] = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
    }
  }
```

Thank you for any light you can help shed on my issue.

Comment: Encode your `$rows` array to json

Comment: Thanks that actually exactly what I need.  I stumbled across encode_json() just after posting this.  \_O_/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you already found your answer but I'll post for completeness.

Simply change your the `var_dump($rows)` line to `json_encode($rows)`.

Read more about [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in the php docs.

You probably want to have two php files:

- `api.php` file that emits `Content-type: application/json`
- `index.php` file that emits `Content-type: text/html` and calls `api.php`

On the index page, you can make an AJAX call to your API endpoint and then use `JSON.parse(response)`.